# vector of std::threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, c++11, stdthread

**C++11**

I am trying to make a `vector` of `std::thread`s. The combination of the following three points says I can.

1.) According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread,
    `thread`’s default constructor creates a

> thread object which does not represent a thread.

2.) According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D, `thread`’s `operator=`

> Assigns the state of [the parameter, which
>           is a thread rvalue reference] to [the calling thread] using move
>           semantics.

3.) According to
    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector, passing
        only a size type variable to a vector constructor will construct

> the container with [the specified number of] value-initialized (default constructed, for
>   classes) instances of T. No copies are made.

**So, I did this:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
    return;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> vecThread(1);
    vecThread.at(0) = std::thread(foo);
    vecThread.at(0).join();
    return 0;
}
```

This runs as expected in VC11 and [g++ 4.8.0 (online compiler here)](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4phwIB$0) as seen in the following:

**Console Output:**

```
Hello
```

**Then I tried it in clang 3.2, by toggling the compiler menu on the same webpage, which gives:**

```
stderr: 
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

When a thread object—that represents a thread—goes out of scope before being `join()`ed or `detach()`ed, the program will be forced to terminate. I have `join()`ed `vecThread.at(0)`, so the only thing left in question is the temporary thread

`std::thread(foo);`

in the

`vecThread.at(0) = std::thread(foo);`

assignment.

However, according to the web reference, threads can only be assigned by moving a thread rvalue reference. I cannot think of any way to `join()` or `detach()` a temporary thread object.

So if clang’s output is correct, then what is the use of `thread`’s `operator=`? Or is this a clang compiler bug?

In g++ 4.8.0, changing the line

`vecThread.at(0) = std::thread(foo)`

to

`vecThread.at(0) = std::thread{foo}`

(replacing parentheses with braces) still gives the expected `Hello` output.

However, changing the line to `vecThread.at(0) = {foo}` makes it complain:

**g++ 4.8.0's complaint on braces:**

> error: converting to 'std::thread' from initializer list would use
>   explicit constructor 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
>   [with _Callable = void (&)(); _Args = {}]'
>        vecThread.at(0) = {foo};

which is too advanced—I don’t know what it means.

Making the same change in clang gives the even more advanced:

**clang 3.2's complaint on braces:**

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
vecThread.at(0) = {foo};
...
note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list
argument to 'const std::thread'
thread& operator=(const thread&) = delete;
...
note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list
argument to 'std::thread'
thread& operator=(thread&& __t) noexcept
```

and I don’t know what that means either.

I cannot use VC11 to corroborate the above

`vecThread.at(0) = {foo}`

problems because VC11, as of the November 2012 CTP compiler, does not support uniform initialization syntax on the Standard Library.

Comment: Did you compile with `-pthread`? The code looks fine, albeit a bit verbose.

Comment: Do you mean I should add `–pthread` to the `compiler/interpreter` arguments text field of the online compiler? I added it to the webpage's text field's original compiler/interpreter arguments, making it `-std=c++11 -Wall -W -pedantic -O2 –pthread` on clang, but got the same results with the `terminate` being called.

Comment: Well, [this code](http://ideone.com/4B2Elt) works for me when compiled with `-std=c++0x -pthread`...

Comment: I wrote a little snippet for liveworkspace named `cfor-dtor tracer`. Play with it instead of std::thread

Comment: AFAIK, this exception throws when you compile with flag `-stdlib=libstdc++`. And this is old known [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12730). Some suggest using a llvm c++ library, but I can't confirm it now. You can check it, if you have installed this library(add `-stdlib=libc++` to compiler arguments).

Comment: @soon: make that an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first example is correct. Throwing an exception is a known [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12730), when you using clang with libstdc++. To solve it, you have to install libc++(llvm version of c++ library). See an example of compiling with libc++ below

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::thread t([] () {});
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

`$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -o main -lc++ -lsupc++ -lpthread`

P.S. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297291/clang-3-1-libc-compile-error), why is the flag `-lsupc++` required too.