# C++ 11 Threads, Error Pure virtual function called

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, beagleboneblack

here is a very minimal C++11 Thread API code that I am trying to compile

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

void threadFunction(void)
{
    cout<<"hello from thread:";//<<this_thread::get_id()<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(threadFunction);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

On Compiling this as 
g++ thread1.cpp -pthread -std=c++11
I get the following error
pure virtual method called

terminate called without an active exception

Aborted

What wrong, can someone please help

Note that I am compiling this on Beaglebone Black with ARM A8 processor

Comment: Sorry, but your code works just fine in VS2012, with default compiler settings. So the code is not the problem.

Comment: What is your OS and compiler versions?

Comment: Maybe you're compiling command is wrong? It's weird. I've tried it here (http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) and it worked. (compile cmd "g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1")

Comment: This is on Beaglebone Black, which runs Angstrom Linux. Also I am using putty to ssh into my beaglebone via usb

Comment: losif Marariu tried your compile command, same error

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171401/why-does-this-simple-c11-threading-example-fail-when-compiled-with-clang-3-2

Comment: It also works fine with GNU C++ 4.7.2 on my Linux Debian (amd64).

Comment: @Scooby That's not how undefined behavior works (undecidability and all). But in this particular case the code really is perfectly acceptable. I run into a different problem with g++ 4.8.1 which is described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201).

Comment: what is your stl library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in either libstdc++ or Clang, depending on who you ask. It should work if you are using a version of Clang released after October 2013. What do you see when you run `g++ --version`?

As a workaround, you could try using this command line instead. I don't guarantee that it would work; please post a comment with your results.

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_{1,2,4} thread1.cpp
```

Here's the bug report:

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12730

And here's the official fix to the Clang driver:

https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=191707

I don't know if this was also previously a bug in the GCC driver, and/or whether it's been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with an ARM Cortex-A7.
Compiled with g++-4.7, turned out the culprit was a compiler flag:

```
-march=armv7-a
```

Answer (score 1):

Although clang had a related issue, this is entirely a gcc bug now recorded at: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62100

Comment: And in fact it's an OpenEmbedded bug.  A better workaround until it's fixed is to use `-mcpu=cortex-a8`.  See the [OE Core thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/openembedded-core@lists.openembedded.org/msg55490.html) for context.