# qmake how to add extra flags

Tags: qt, gcc, qmake

I am using qmake to cross-compile my ARM based program on Ubuntu. I have ran into the multithreading issue as described in this thread:

[C++ 11 Threads, Error Pure virtual function called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583317/c-11-threads-error-pure-virtual-function-called)

One answer suggests adding the flag to the compilation as:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_{1,2,4} thread1.cpp
```

I am not sure how to add this `-D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_{1,2,4}` in my qmake project file.

I did `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_{1,2,4}`. My error still remains so I wanted to confirm if this is the right way to add that flag.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bash glob/wildcard. Expands to

`-D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_1 -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_2 -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_4`